# What does "Reflection along the subspace generated by v" means?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, euclidean-geometry, reflection

I got a problem which includes "Reflection along the subspace generated by $v$ in $\mathbf{R}^{n+1}$". I need some clarification, what does it mean? Does it mean reflection about the hyperplane $v^{\bot}$?

Comment: I would interpret it as reflection in the one-dimensional subspace consisting of the scalar multiples of $v$. But first I'd read the rest of whatever the problem says, and see whether I could deduce the meaning from context. And if I couldn't, then I would ask the person who gave me the problem what interpretation she would give.

Comment: Anything to say, PSG?

Comment: Well I think it's as you said in the first comment. Reflection in the 1d subspace. To solve the problem I need it continuous, better if  we can get a formula

Comment: Do you know how to compute the projection of a vector onto the subspace of scalar multiples of $v$?

Comment: Yeah...then? We need to get the reflection formula

Comment: Does the (projection part - the rest of the vector) gives the reflection formula?

Comment: Think about what happens when you add the vector to its reflection – how does that sum relate to the projection? It may help to draw a picture in two dimensions.

Comment: Ohh...I think  I got it. Reflection should be (2 times projection- the actual vector). Is it correct?

Comment: Good! Let me encourage you to write it up and post it as an answer.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.

Comment: I have written it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Gerry Myerson who guided me to solve this problem. Here is the solution:

let $\mathbf{r}$ be the reflection of the original vector $\mathbf{x}$, along the subspace generated by $\mathbf{v}$. Then both $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{x}$ has same projection onto $\mathbf{v}$ as reflection along $\mathbf{v}$ will keep the projection onto $\mathbf{v}$ intact.

So, $\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{r}= 2 \times $ (Projection of $\mathbf{x}$ onto the subspace of scalar multiples of $\mathbf{v})= {2 x \cdot v\over \|v\|^2}v\Rightarrow \mathbf{r}={2 x \cdot v\over \|v\|^2}v- \mathbf{x}$